# What is a 'braid Galois group'?

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, reference-request

[During this lecture](https://vimeo.com/240937391#t=860s) given by Jesse Wolfson on the resolvent degree of a kind of cover, he mentions an object called a **braid Galois group**. In looking through the arXiv and MathSciNet, I haven't been able to come up with any literature on it.

Does anyone have a reference for this group, or a direction to point me in?

Comment: Might be of some help: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vrHopW5yI3s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vrHopW5yI3s)

Comment: I do not think this is a standard terminology.